# Spark 1.6 with Kryo 2.21 and ArrayList

Tags: java, apache-spark, kryo

I am trying to use Spark 1.6.0 with Kryo 2.21. Its really frustrating as I am not able to figure out what is causing this error.

I do not see anything at line 234 in Arraylist class which could cause a Null Pointer. Does having kryo 2.22 as well on class-path is causing this. Please help. Thanks

```
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ABC");
        conf.set("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.class.getName());
        conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class[] { ArrayList.class, VC.class, DC.class });
```

Stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:234)
        at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:218)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:89)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:18)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you share your code? That error seems to be from Java Array class not your code.

Comment: Yes, I will make minimal version of code and share.